# IBM Worklight 6.1 - Rich Page Editor does not refresh after making a change

Tags: css, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-rpe

I am using JQuery Mobile and Worklight to create a web app and am having some issues with Worklight's design view (RPE).

Specifically, the design view seems to have a bug. When I update the appearance of a button in an external CSS file.  The CSS code in question:

```
#mapButton { 
position: absolute;
height: 100px;
width: 200px;
top:75%;
left:50%;
text-align: center;
line-height: 50px;
}
```

If I change say the height, the design view displays the button at its default size at the top of the html page.  Any subsequent changes are not reflected in the design view.  It is only when I restart Eclipse that the button is now displayed with its updated properties.  When I build the application and preview it via the Worklight console the button is displayed as expected (even if it is displayed incorrectly in the design view).

Is there any solution to this problem or is this some known bug?

Comment: Windows? Mac? Did you try clicking on the refresh button in the menu bar of the design view?

Comment: I am running Windows and I never saw that feature thank you!  The answer is exceedingly simple and saves me a headache.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing may be a defect and it will be investigated, however as a workaround you can click on the Refresh button the RPE toolbar to refresh the design view.